# Exporting a list to Excel and OpenOffice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I have one list where I need to export data in excel. The Code in View:

```html
 $("#btnExport").click(function () {
        //Used for Export to excel
         window.open('@Url.Action("ExportHotelUtilizationListToExcel","DutyTravel")');

    });

<input type="button" value="Export to Excel" name="submitButton" id="btnExport" class="k-button" />
```

and below is my controller method

```html
 public FileResult ExportHotelUtilizationListToExcel()
        {
            var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
            
            List<DutyTravelHotelUtilization> lstSeparation = null;
            if (Session["HotelUtilizationDetails"] != null)
            {
                lstSeparation = (List<DutyTravelHotelUtilization>)HttpContext.Session["HotelUtilizationDetails"];
                grid.DataSource = from d in lstSeparation
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        RequestCode = d.DutyTravelReqId,
                                        StffNumber = d.StaffNumber,
                                        StaffName = d.StaffName,
                                        CityCode = d.CityCode,
                                        CityName = d.CityName,
                                        HotelCategory = d.HotelCategory,
                                        HotelName = d.HotelName,
                                        CurrencyInQAR = d.QurrencyQAR,
                                        CheckInDate = Convert.ToDateTime(d.CheckInDate).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
                                        CheckOutDate = Convert.ToDateTime(d.CheckOutDate).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
                                        Duration = d.Duration
                                    };
            }
            grid.DataBind();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sw.ToString()), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Contacts.xlsx");
        }
```

It is showing download option and able to open in OpenOffice but in MS Office 2010 showing error message about some format issue.

Comment: does it work with .xls extension and application/vnd.ms-excel mime type? what exactly the error says?

Comment: I have changed mime type as suggested by you now the message i am getting is the file format and extension of <filename> does not match. the file could be corrupted or unsafe. unless you trust this source don't open it. when i click on yes it is opening fine but why this message i am getting?

Comment: did you change extension to xls too?

Comment: Yes i changed but getting the same message while opening file

Comment: might be that some part of what youre trying to export are not valid for excel (some headings, or characters), try to simplify it as possible and export again. You may also provide some data that works in tutorials to see if the rest is fine.

Comment: Mikus, Error message is showing that is ok but when i click on yes data is showing fine in the file. The problem i have that without showing error message should generate file. If you have example code or any link which export to excel without showing this message then it will be good.

Comment: I dont, you may find tutorials on the internet, if this is the case, most likely part of your data (Content or format) is wrong, google the exact error message, try to strip data (reduce the amount to only headers, try different encoding, use only basic ascii characters, etc,) at one point you'll find the reason

Comment: Any one who knows how to export list to excel using openxml in mvc?